# How can I track the delivery status of the sent email in "Send an email" Azure Logic App Outlook Connector

Tags: azure-logic-apps

When using Azure Logic App Office 365 Outlook connector - "Send an email", is there a way to find out if the email was actually delivered or not to the recipient so as to take a specific action based on the failure?

I used an invalid email ID in the connector, but the action of sending email is shown as successful even though the email was not delivered. To confirm it is an invalid email ID, I sent email to this invalid email ID from my Outlook and I received an undelivered email message.

In the next action after this “Send an email” action, I selected the 3 options (has failed, is skipped, has timed out) under “Configure run after”. However, this action is never executed as the email sending action is always successful even though the email was never delivered to the user.

Below is a screenshot of my logic app. The bottom right action in yellow is never executed even though the email is not sent in the previous step.

[Send Email Logic App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuEF5.jpg)

Any inputs on how I can find out if the email was actually delivered or not?
My goal here is to find out if the user actually received the email or not, and then take some action if the email delivery failed.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible from within the Logic App.

The only way to occasionally accomplish this is to monitor the sender inbox for NDRs (Non-Delivery Receipt).  This can take minutes to hours.

Be aware, a number of email systems will not even send NDRs as they can be used to fish for email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use get emails action to get the latest email and you can perform the next action based on the condition whether the subject of the email we get contains the "Undelivered" string.

Sometimes it takes long to receive the undelivered report email in outlook. so i made a specific flow which will extract the wrong email that i sent the mail to and send me an adaptive card with that email provided in it.

Comment: It would help to OP to describe the "get emails action" and perhaps detail where to find the list of "undelivered emails".  Would also help to describe the "specific flow" you referred to -- for example describe what technology you used to implement the flow.  Would also be helpful to describe the "adaptive card" that you mentioned.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).